# Raspberry Pi 3, browser permissions on apache2 php script

Tags: php, apache, permissions, raspberry-pi3, chromium

Having a nightmare with permissions on RP3, apache2, php

I can run my php api script from terminal with no problems. I use the browser for debugging and get the 'permission denied' when trying to edit text files from the browser.

I have temporarily set permissions to 777 on /var/www but this is insecure, and i can no longer remember the original permissions that were on /var/www

Can i somehow give the broswer (chromium) permission to edit files in /var/www?

I have tried setting inheritance, but to no avail, as i am copying files over all the time, i have to keep resetting the permissions to 777 (which is not ideal), so i can debug the code in a browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Rgds

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the permissions for folders are `0755` and for folders are `0644`.

To set the permissions for folders:

```
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

To set the permissions for files:

```
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Now about the `user/group`, Apache is probably using the user `www-data` with group `www-data`.

To set the user/group for write permissions:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R
```

**A note about security:** opening up the option to edit the files from the browser is insecure without any login, allowing anyone to edit your files. Also, the write permissions should only be allowed in a directory where the users upload files and NOT for all your `/var/www` files.

Comment: Thank you for help! I remember those values now, and i appreciate it. So i made all those changes. I couldn't edit the scripts, so i had to change the files one to 0646. Now i cannot delete a file, it says permission denied, I don't suppose you know what i need to change them to, to be able to delete a file under /var/www ?

Comment: I just tested my answer with your problem on my Raspberry Pi and it works. There must be something else you are not doing right.

Comment: I opened up explorer and i don't have permission to delete a file in a subfolder in /var/www? Error message: Unable to move file /var/www/html/test/test.txt to the wastebasket: Permission denied.

Comment: Are you sure that you ran the last command? the one with `chown`?

Comment: Yes, I ran get_current_user() in the script in a subfolder in /var/www and it showed www-data. I also ran getcwd() which showed /home/pi ? Does that make a difference?

Comment: No. Just make sure your files are under `/var/www` folder. If they are somewhere else, just run `chown` command above to your new path.

Comment: The files i am trying to delete are in /var/www - permission denied. Should i start a new question, with this issue?

Comment: If you do, put it on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) or [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I put this exact problem on raspberrypi.stackexchanged.com and they closed it for 'off  topic'? I will try serverfault.com, thank you.

Comment: I guessed that i had managed to screwup permissions in general, and probably broke something else. So, i started from scratch, wiped the sd card, new OS, etc. I went through your suggestions above, and it now all works wonderfully. I wanted to come back and thank you for your time and help!!!!

Comment: That's nice. You're welcome! Please accept my answer by clicking the ticker besides my answer.